# Android - ArrayList and RecycleView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have got my `ChordsListActivity` that looks like this:

```
public class ChordsListActivity extends Activity {
private RecyclerView chordsList;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager listLayoutManager;

private ArrayList<Accordo> getChords() {
    ArrayList<Accordo> chords = new ArrayList<>();

    Accordo a=new Accordo();
    a.setName("Do maggiore");
    a.setNote("Do, Mi, Sol");
    a.setImage(R.drawable.do_maggiore);
    chords.add(a);

    a=new Accordo();
    a.setName("do 5");
    a.setNote("na, na, na");
    a.setImage(R.drawable.do5);
    chords.add(a);

    return chords;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chords_list);

    chordsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chords_recycler);

    //use a linear layout manager
    listLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    chordsList.setLayoutManager(listLayoutManager);

     ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(this, getChords());

    /** start SearchActivity when ImageButton is pressed */
    ImageButton cerca = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
    cerca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);

            ArrayList<Accordo> chords = new ArrayList<Accordo>();
            intent.putExtra("chords", chords);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

There is an error on this line:

```
ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(this, getChords());
```

this is the error:

> Error:(126, 38) error: constructor ChordsListAdapter in class ChordsListAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: ArrayList
>   found: ChordsListActivity,ArrayList
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

and this is my `ChordsListAdapter`:

```
public class ChordsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChordsListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Accordo> chordsList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView nome, note;
    public ImageView immagine;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        note = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note);
        immagine = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.immagine_accordo);
    }
}

public ChordsListAdapter(ArrayList<Accordo> chordsList) {
    this.chordsList = chordsList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    Accordo chord = chordsList.get(position);
    holder.nome.setText(chord.getNome());
    holder.note.setText(chord.getNote());
    holder.immagine.setImageResource(chord.getImage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chordsList.size();
}
}
```

could you help me figure out what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: can you post code of getChords() method

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi there is already, it's the method that returns the ArrayList in the ChordsListActivity

Comment: you are passing  (this, getChords()) two params and  you have constructor of 1 param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(this, getChords());
```

is a call to the Constructor of your `ChordsListAdapter`, which looks like this in you `ChordsListAdapter.class`:

```
public ChordsListAdapter(ArrayList<Accordo> chordsList) {
    this.chordsList = chordsList; 
}
```

Either you'll need to change your constructor to accept a  `Context` or an `Activity`.

```
public ChordsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Accordo> chordsList) {
    this.chordsList = chordsList; 
}
```

or you can delete the first parameter in the call:

```
ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(getChords());
```

Comment: Thank you! great answer! that fixed it, even though my recycler view still looks empty when I try to run it. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: This seems like a problem for another question, since I can't see a problem with your code so far ;) Possible causes: your `xml` (activity layout, row layout) is not coded properly.

Comment: strange... the error has to be there because my classes are only this two and my xml layout used to work before I changed my ArrayList

Comment: of course the problem was that I did not set the adapter. Now I fixed it

Comment: Totally did not see that. Glad you found your error so quick :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have only one constructor

```
public ChordsListAdapter(ArrayList<Accordo> chordsList) {
    this.chordsList = chordsList;
}
```

it doesn't have an activity as parameter, so you have to change the way you create your adapter like this:

```
ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(getChords());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one constructor

```
ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(this, getChords());

public ChordsListAdapter(ArrayList<Accordo> chordsList) {
    this.chordsList = chordsList;
}
```

it doesn't have an activity as parameter, so you have to change the adapter like below:

```
ChordsListAdapter adapter = new ChordsListAdapter(getChords());
```